# DB Schema for counting unread emails per mailbox

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am building an email web app, and having trouble coming up with a schema that will quickly give me the count of unread emails per folder.

My schema at the moment looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE emails(id INT, user_id INT, folder INT, 
    read_on TIMESTAMP, raw_email_filename VARCHAR(128));
```

To get the unread count for each folder I could run a query like:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM email WHERE user_id =? AND folder IN (?..) AND read_on IS NULL;
```

But this would have to traverse all the email on each folder to get the count, given my index is `(user_id, folder)`.

I was thinking about adding an index `(user_id, folder, read_on)` but this would have far too many entries for `read_on`, when I am only interested in the `NULL` values for `read_on`.

Is there a better way to do it? Maybe with de-normalization? Keeping count in Redis or something?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider

```
INDEX(user_id, read_on, folder)
```

The guideline for building an optimal index is to *first* list the columns tested with `=` (`IS NULL` counts as such), then `INs` (`folder`), then one range (you don't have any).

Don't worry about the wasted index entries for the `read_on IS NOT NULL` entries; they clutter the disk without hurting performance.

On the other hand, when you change `read_on` (via `UPDATE`?), there is a slight hit because an entry in my proposed `INDEX` needs to move from one spot to another in the index BTree.  Again, this is probably not worth worrying about.

And don't you want a `GROUP BY`?

```
SELECT folder, COUNT(*)
    FROM emails
    WHERE user_id = ?
      AND folder IN (...)
      AND read_on IS NULL
    GROUP BY folder;
```

Do `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  With my `INDEX`, the `EXPLAIN` will probably say `Using index`, indicating a "covering" index.  That's one where *all* the columns needed are in the index.

More on index creation: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql